# TFS Support and Migration to SharePoint 2019

Tags: tfs, sharepoint-2019

I have one TFS integrated site on SharePoint 2013 environment. Now we are planning to upgrade our environment to SharePoint 2019. Just wanted to check whether TFS integration still supported in SP 2019.

- If it is, what should be the approach?
- If not, what options I have for my TFS site?

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint integration is no longer supported as of TFS 2018 and Azure DevOps Server 2019. Sharepoint 2016 is only supported with a workaround. Sharepoint 2019 is not supported.

```
TFS version Supported SharePoint versions
TFS 2018    No longer supported
TFS 2017    SharePoint 2013 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise) 
            SharePoint 2010 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)
TFS 2015    SharePoint 2013 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)
            SharePoint 2010 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)
TFS 2013    SharePoint 2013 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)
            SharePoint 2010 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)
TFS 2012    SharePoint 2013 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)
            SharePoint 2010 (Foundation, Standard, Enterprise)
            Office SharePoint Server 2007 (Standard, Enterprise)
            Windows SharePoint Services 3.0
TFS 2010    Office SharePoint Server 2007 (Standard, Enterprise)
            Windows SharePoint Services 3.0
```

Details here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sharepoint-dashboards/about-sharepoint-integration?view=azure-devops
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sharepoint-dashboards/deprecation/discontinue-pre-tfs-2017-sharepoint-integration?view=tfs-2017&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops

These posts also offer alternate options:

- use analytics service in TFS/Azure DevOps optionally combined with PowerBI/PowerBI Server. You can embed these in Sharepoint.
- use dashboards in TFS/Azure DevOps
- use markdown/wiki to cross link between Sharepoint and Azru DeOps

Your existing ShasePoint sites need to be unlinked from TFS, the widgets will stop working. Your document libraries etc will just work as they always did.

Comment: What's with the -1?